# Error when accessing raw pixel data of resized image

Tags: ios, image, resize, core-graphics, cgcontext

I have some problems with access to camera images (or even images from photalbum).

After resizing the `UIImage` (i tested several different resize methods, they all lead to the same error) I want to access every individual pixel for handing over to a complex algorithm.

The problem is, that there is often a bytesPerRow value that doesn't match to the image size (eg. width*4) when accessing raw pixel data with `CGImageGetDataProvider` -> resulting in a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error.

Maybe we have an iOS bug here…

Nonetheless, here is the code:

```m
// UIImage  capturedImage from Camera

CGImageRef capturedImageRef = capturedImage.CGImage;

// getting bits per component from capturedImage
size_t bitsPerComponentOfCapturedImage = CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(capturedImageRef);
CGImageAlphaInfo alphaInfoOfCapturedImage = CGImageGetAlphaInfo(capturedImageRef);
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

// calculate new size from interface data. 
// with respect to aspect ratio

// ...

// newWidth = XYZ;
// newHeight = XYZ;

CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, newWidth, newHeight, bitsPerComponentOfCapturedImage,0 , colorSpace, alphaInfoOfCapturedImage);

// I also tried to make use getBytesPerRow for CGBitmapContextCreate resulting in the same error

// if image was rotated
if(capturedImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationRight) {
  CGContextRotateCTM(context, -M_PI_2);
  CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -newHeight, 0.0f);
}

// draw on new context with new size
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight), capturedImage.CGImage);

CGImageRef scaledImage=CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

// release
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
CGContextRelease(context);
theImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: scaledImage];

CGImageRelease(scaledImage);
```

After that, I want to access the scaled image by

```m
CGImageRef imageRef = theImage.CGImage;
NSData *data        = (NSData *) CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(imageRef));

unsigned char *pixels        = (unsigned char *)[data bytes];

// create a new image from the modified pixel data
size_t width                    = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
size_t height                   = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
size_t bitsPerComponent         = CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef);
size_t bitsPerPixel             = CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(imageRef);
size_t bytesPerRow              = CGImageGetBytesPerRow(imageRef);

CGDataProviderRef provider      = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, pixels, [data length], NULL);

NSLog(@"bytesPerRow: %f ", (float)bytesPerRow);
NSLog(@"Image width: %f ", (float)width);
NSLog(@"Image height: %f ", (float)height);

// manipulate the individual pixels
for(int i = 0; i < [data length]; i += 4) {

  // accessing (float) pixels[i];
  // accessing (float) pixels[i+1];
  // accessing (float) pixels[i+2];

}
```

So for example when I access an image with 511x768 Pixel and scale that down to 290x436 I get following output:

**Image width:** 290.000000

**Image height:** 436.000000

**bitsPerComponent:** 8.000000

**bitsPerPixel:** 32.000000

**bytesPerRow:** 1184.000000

and you can clearly see that the bytesPerRow (althought choosen automatically by cocoa) does **not** match to the image `width`.

I would love to see any help

---

Using `iOS` `SDK 4.3` on `Xcode 4`

Comment: using conversion to pngrepresentation as work arround

Answer (score 1):

You are ignoring possible line-padding, hence receiving invalid results. Add the following code and replace your loop;

```
size_t bytesPerPixel = bitsPerPixel / bitsPerComponent;
//calculate the padding just to see what is happening
size_t padding = bytesPerRow - (width * bytesPerPixel);
size_t offset = 0;
// manipulate the individual pixels
while (offset < [data length])
{
  for (size_t x=0; x < width; x += bytesPerPixel)
  {
    // accessing (float) pixels[offset+x];
    // accessing (float) pixels[offset+x+1];
    // accessing (float) pixels[offset+x+2];
  }
  offset += bytesPerRow;
};
```

Addendum: Underlying reasoning for the row-padding is optimizing the memory access for individual rows to 32bit boundaries. It is indeed very common and is done for optimization purposes.

Comment: First. Yes there is padding. Depending on the view aspect ratio and the device rotation eg. when resizing to a given width the padding is 24 when resizing to given height there is no padding.

But I still do not understand why the "line-padding" you were talking about takes place? Whats the underlying reason?

Comment: added addendum to answer your additional question above. If my solution/answer solved your issues, please check on the grey checkmark to the left of my answer and upvote it using the up-arrow.

Comment: thank you so much for your help!

So let me sum this up: When I resize the Uiimage, and access the CGImageRef representation of the resized image, I always have to check for this padding, right? Does this also apply when I render the image to a new CALayer, or draw on the image itself and then later access the raw pixel values?

Is there a way to avoid this (eg. by accepting slow resizing) and have a cleanly "allocated" image?

Comment: Oh, and do you have any idea, where I can learn more about that topic. It's not mentioned in the API Documentation at all... nor anything here on stackoverflow...

Comment: Check my version of that loop again an you will find that padding is not an issue as long as you form your image data processing that way. Do never assume anything but always use all the information you get from CoreGraphics. Instead of assuming a row-size, I used the bytesPerRow information.